# Does ECR public registry has native API support similar to ECR private registry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, amazon-ecr-public

I can see there are native API's available to query some of the data for repositories in ECR private registry.
e.g.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetImage.html

AWS SDK Go:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ecr/#ECR.BatchGetImage

This give you the config for an image matching the input criteria.

Does ECR public registry also supports these kinds of native APIs? I know /v2/repo/manifest/tag V2 API available to fetch the config but I'm looking for native/SDK API call.

Comment: This is the API for ECR Public https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECRPublic/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html